# zend framework and jquery - attach event from server side?

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

I have a form I created with `Zend_Form` (or `Zend_JQuery_Form` now).

I have a select box in the form and I would like to do a call-back to the server when the user selects a value (to create dependent select boxes).

Is there any way to specify the "**change**" event code from the server side? or just to write the **jquery** client side myself?

Thanks.

Comment: i would implement it by my self (Jquery Support will be stopped in ZF 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That is possible to add in the server side itself. While creating your form element, add the details for the onchange event like shown below.

```
$titleElement = $form->createElement('text', 'title', array(
'onchange' => 'alert(this.value);'
'label' => 'This is the title'
));
```