# Zend_form_element_select onchange in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a form named createDevice.php as:

```
class Admin_Form_CreateDevice extends Zend_Form
{
public function init()
{
    $this->setName('Create Device Access');
    $sort=new Zend_Form_Element_Select('employee_name');
    $sort->setLabel('Employee Name:');
    $this->addElements(array($sort));
    /* Form Elements & Other Definitions Here ... */
}

}
```

Now In controller action named viewDeviceAction() I have called this form as:

```
public function viewDeviceAction()
{
    echo 'viewDevice: ';
    $form_device=new Admin_Form_CreateDevice();
    $form_device->setMethod('post');
    $form_device->employee_name->addMultiOptions($aMembers);//here $aMembers is an array.
    $this->view->form=$form_device;
 }
```

Now I want following situation:
On selecting any value from above dropdown a javascript function (which resides in viewDevice.phtml ) should be called.Like in general html as:

```
<select id="EmployeeId" onchange="loadDeviceId();">
```

So I just want to khow that how to implement the onchange event on the select element in zend framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is possible to add in the server side itself. While creating your element, add the details for the onchange event like shown below.

```
$sort=new Zend_Form_Element_Select('employee_name',array('onchange' => 'loadDeviceId();'));
```

Now in your output HTML, you will see `"onchange = 'loadDeviceId();'"` attached to your select element.

Check [my answer in an other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344895/zend-framework-and-jquery-attach-event-from-server-side/8624359#8624359).

Comment: here I did the same thing but when I click on any option of select , javascript function is not called and that page reloads again but no javascript function is called. Why this is occuring?When I see the page source its right as it shows:          <select name="employee_name" id="employee_name" onchange="submit();">Plz suggest me.

Comment: did u check in Firebug? what is the code inside submit javascript function?

Comment: Yup I checked in firebug and on change it is not going in javascript function.This function has an alert.

Comment: Now What I did instead of echo $this->form I just copy the view source of that page and copied into phtml file and when I eliminate form tag it is actually going into javascript function here form tag is as follows:  <form id="create device access" name="create device access" action="" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> after removing form tag javascript function runs.Why??I think in my opinion since there is no action thats why form reloads.But I have to call javascript function.Now what has to be done??

Comment: you can echo only the select element like `echo $sort;` form tag wont appear in the HTML code

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to implement an event handler for the `onChange`event you will have to do it in javascript.
<strike>There is no native way to implement it in PHP or Zend framework as far as I know.</strike>

Using JQuery you could do something like this:

```
$('#employee_name').change(function() 
{
   //call your javascript function here
});
```

You can even call your function directly like this:

```
$('#employee_name').change(yourFunctionName);
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: I know how to implement javascript with jquery and all.But the thing is that How I have to call that javascript function on selecting any value from dropdown?and that dropdown is made in Zend_form.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get your problem. The element you created in Zend form has an id of "employee_name". You can use this id to attach the event handler to the form element. In my example if a change event is fired on the "employee_name" a callback function (yourFunctionName) will be executed.

Comment: It is actually possible to add the `onChange` attribute in the form class itself, see @emaillenin's answer.

Comment: @Salman Thanks for the notifier. Actually I didn't quite get what he was trying to do, but after seeing his modified post I realized that emaillenin's answer was the correct solution.